# React-Native <ImageBackground/> on Android does not render image

Tags: android, react-native

If I run this Snack on Expo on my Android device, it shows the image fine: https://snack.expo.io/@kovek/imagebackground-example

If I run that same code serving from my React 62 packager, with the bundle running on my Android device, the image does not show.

The issue is specifically with this URI: https://c.tile.openstreetmap.org/5/5/12.png (and other configurations of tiles from that server.)

For example, this JPG works fine: http://placekitten.com/300/300 (a kitten) , and this PNG works fine: https://i.dlpng.com/static/png/357627_preview.png (it's a galaxy)

It also didn't show on the Android emulator on Linux

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issue where image was NOT displayed on release versions whereas it was displayed on DEBUG mode(emulator, testing devices)
Figured out that **http** url did not work in release mode hence started using **https** url which worked like a charm at both the places.